# How to properly setup snapper timeline snapshots in debian buster?

Tags: btrfs, snapper

I recently created a btrfs partition. Now I want to use `snapper` to perform automatic snapshots. The partition is used as an archive, as a backup disk for my main office pc. Generally speaking, the partition is only used two to three times a week ==> so there is no need for too many snapshots at all.

Unfortunately snapper is creating lots of snapshots. Now I have about twenty snapshots with zero difference. So how do I have to change my config, to reduce the number of snapshots created by snapper.

Actl. my config says

```
TIMELINE_CLEANUP       | yes
TIMELINE_CREATE        | yes
TIMELINE_LIMIT_DAILY   | 1
TIMELINE_LIMIT_HOURLY  | 1
TIMELINE_LIMIT_MONTHLY | 4
TIMELINE_LIMIT_WEEKLY  | 2
TIMELINE_LIMIT_YEARLY  | 2
TIMELINE_MIN_AGE       | 1800
```

but regarding to `snapper -c buerossd-subdata-snap list` I have about twenty snapshots, created hourly. How can that be, because regarding to my config file it should only save 1 per hour and a max of 1 per day or 2 per week.

If you want to review my full output [here is a pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/VeUByVPG).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can that be, because regarding to my config file it should only save 1 per hour and a max of 1 per day or 2 per week.

According to your configuration, `snapper -c buerossd-subdata-sna cleanup timeline` should **keep** only one hourly. `snapper ... cleanup` is usually called by cron or a systemd-timer. However `snapper ... cleanup` is called a lot less than `snapper ... create` in the usual configuration, at least on Debian Buster.

Have a look at `systemctl list-timers snapper*`. There should be at least two timers:

- `snapper-timeline.timer` for `snapper-timeline.service`, which creates the new snapshots
- `snapper-cleanup.timer` for `snapper-cleanup.service`, which removes snapshots according to your configuration

By default, `snapper-cleanup.service` runs once a day:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/snapper-cleanup.timer

[Unit]
Description=Daily Cleanup of Snapper Snapshots
Documentation=man:snapper(8) man:snapper-configs(5)

[Timer]
OnBootSec=10m
OnUnitActiveSec=1d

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Whereas `snapper-timeline.service` runs hourly:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/snapper-timeline.timer

[Unit]
Description=Timeline of Snapper Snapshots
Documentation=man:snapper(8) man:snapper-configs(5)

[Timer]
OnCalendar=hourly

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Which explains the 20 snapshots. After all, if you create a snapshot every hour, then you will have up to 24 snapshots before the cleanup service gets called.

You can either run `snapper-timeline` less or `snapper-cleanup` more often to fix the amount of snapshots. Since you seem to be concerned about the residing number of snapshots you probably want to change the former:

```
systemctl edit snapper-timeline.timer
```

Use appropriate values e.g.

```
[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=12h
OnCalendar=
```

For more information see `man 5 systemd.timer`.